# How to change prettyphoto thumbnail style

Tags: jquery, css, image, prettyphoto

In my prettyphoto the thumbnail  image overlay shows above the large image.I want to show the thumbnail images below the large image.how can I achieve this,any one help?Here below I attached both the images.

[image: My Image]

[image: Need to Like This]

Comment: How far you have tried? You need to change the css.

Comment: This is a CSS issue -- easy to fix.  In the PrettyPhoto CSS file on line 134 (assuming you are using the normal CSS files), you would change something around the class `.pp_gallery`'s `margin-top` attribute.  If you will post your code, we could help get a final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your css to below, might work for you

```
    .pp_gallery {
            display: none;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10000;
        }
    div.pp_default .pp_content_container .pp_details {
            margin-top: 30px;
    }
```

**FOR THUMBNAIL
CSS**

```
.pp_gallery {
            display: block;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10000;
        }
```

**IN JS**

Commented out this line

```
function(){
    //$pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_gallery:not(.disabled)').fadeIn();
},
function(){
    //$pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_gallery:not(.disabled)').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: yes.its working ..but the problem is the large image remain the same,I need to change the height of the large image ,is it possible,then which class I need to change..?

Comment: use firebug for firefox than you can edit it on fly and make your changes and see  it.

Comment: its okey..now the thumbnail images shows only the mouse over.how can we show the thumbnail images always.

Comment: I commented the above steps in JS ,then the thumbnail not showing.I want to show the thumbnails every time(now its showing only in the mouse over).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38785/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-arun)